# Copy a function instead of referencing

Tags: variable-definitions

Is there an option to let me assign the old function of f to g, without changing g when reassigning f?

This piece of code describes my problem:

```
f[x_] := x^2

f[2] (*Output: 4*)

g = f

g[2] (*Output: 4*)

f[x_] := x^3

f[2] (*Output: 8*)
g[2] (*Output: 8*)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clear your current `g` and `f`. Start from a fresh kernel and use

[`ResourceFunction["CopyDefinitions"][f, g];`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CopyDefinitions/)

See the notebook on the WFR if you want to see how this is achieved.
(The `CopySymbol` defined there is basically taking `` Language`ExtendedDefinition[f] `` and replacing the symbol)

```
Remove["Global`*"]
f[x_] := x^2
f[2] (*Output:4*)
ResourceFunction["CopyDefinitions"][f, g];
g[2] (*Output:4*)
f[x_] := x^3
f[2] (*Output:8*)
g[2] (*Output:4*)
```

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* is an expression rewriting system. Your problem is that

```
g=f
```

Means "whenever you see `g`, substitute `f`". So, `g[2]` gets rewritten as `f[2]` which then gets rewritten according to the definition of `f`.

Here, you may do

```
g[x_]=f[x]
```

This evaluates `f[x]` and uses that for your `g` definition. Redefining `f` then has no effect.

This will require more elaboration if evaluating `f` with a symbolic argument causes trouble.